# How to detect the launcher is brought to foreground in Android

Tags: android

I know there is a way to achieve this by using `ActivityManager.getRunningTasks()`. However this requires polling and will consume too much battery. I'm wondering whether there is a mechanism similar to BroadcastReceiver by which I can be notified every time the launcher is brought to foreground.

Answer (score -2):

I think retrieve information by using `ActivityManager.getRunningTasks()` is the only way temporarily.You can try to combine your code snippet to determine the package name of the foreground process with a call to PackageManager to get information about the HOME activity.

```
 public ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo getForegroundTask()
    { 
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService( Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
        return am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);
    } 

    public String getForegroundTaskPackageName()
    { 
        return getForegroundTask().topActivity.getPackageName();
    } 

  public String getCurrentHomePackageName()
    {    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
         intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
         ResolveInfo resolveInfo = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent,     PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        return resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as I said, this method requires polling and consequently consume too much battery.